# Why did I get "Requirements installation failed with status: 1" error with RVM?

Tags: ruby, macos, sass

This is the message my terminal gave back to me when trying to update Ruby using RVM on a Macbook Pro, OS X Lion 10.7.5, with Command Line Tools, XCode, and Homebrew installed.

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig apple-gcc42 libiconv libyaml libffi readline libksba openssl curl-ca-bundle sqlite3 zlib gdbm ncurses',
please read /Users/ADMIN/.rvm/log/1378814732_ruby-2.0.0-p247/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkgconfig_apple-gcc42_libiconv_libyaml_libffi_readline_libksba_openssl_curl-ca-bundle_sqlite3_zlib_gdbm_ncurses.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Here is the result from the log file:

```
[2013-09-10 07:34:31] requirements_osx_port_libs_install
requirements_osx_port_libs_install () 
{ 
    __rvm_try_sudo port install "$@" || { 
        typeset ret=$?;
        rvm_warn "There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.";
        return $ret
    }
}
current path: /Users/ADMIN/.rvm/src/rvm
command(17): requirements_osx_port_libs_installautoconf automake libtool pkgconfig apple-gcc42 libiconv libyaml libffi readline libksba openssl curl-ca-bundle sqlite3 zlib gdbm ncurses
--->  Computing dependencies for autoconf
--->  Dependencies to be installed: help2man gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses p5.12-locale-gettext perl5.12 gdbm m4 perl5 xz
--->  Fetching distfiles for expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://superb-dca3.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://sea.us.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://distfiles.macports.org/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://mse.uk.distfiles.macports.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://aarnet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://her.gr.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports/mpdistfiles/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://aarnet.au.distfiles.macports.org/pub/macports/mpdistfiles/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://internode.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://jog.id.distfiles.macports.org/macports/mpdistfiles/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://cjj.kr.distfiles.macports.org/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://waix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://ignum.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://fco.it.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/expat
--->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/distfiles/expat
Error: org.macports.fetch for port expat returned: fetch failed
Error: Failed to install expat
Please see the log file for port expat for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: help2man gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses p5.12-locale-gettext perl5.12 gdbm m4 perl5 xz
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port autoconf failed
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
```

Any ideas? Expat?

Answer (score 0):

Something's up with your rvm or homebrew install (do you have homebrew installed?).  Try `rvm get head` and `brew doctor` and then follow the instructions to get things updated.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the delay. I'll run these at the earliest convenience and update on what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this line is significant:

```
Error: org.macports.fetch for port expat returned: fetch failed
```

It's pretty obvious the code tried searching through a bunch of mirrors looking for that file. A quick spot-check I just did shows the file is available at a bunch of the sites, so maybe your internet connection was messed up.

```
require 'httpclient'

clnt = HTTPClient.new

%w[
  http://superb-dca3.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://sea.us.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://mse.uk.distfiles.macports.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://aarnet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://her.gr.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://aarnet.au.distfiles.macports.org/pub/macports/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://internode.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://jog.id.distfiles.macports.org/macports/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://cjj.kr.distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://waix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://ignum.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://fco.it.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
  ].each do |url|
  begin
    request = clnt.head(url)
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Failed reading #{url}: \"#{e.message}\""
    next
  end
  if request.status == 200
    puts "#{ url } exists"
  else
    puts '%s ==> %s' % [url, request.headers['Location']]
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
http://superb-dca3.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz ==> http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz?download&failedmirror=superb-dca3.dl.sourceforge.net
http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://sea.us.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz ==> http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz?download&failedmirror=iweb.dl.sourceforge.net
http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://mse.uk.distfiles.macports.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://aarnet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://her.gr.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://aarnet.au.distfiles.macports.org/pub/macports/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://internode.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://jog.id.distfiles.macports.org/macports/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://cjj.kr.distfiles.macports.org/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://waix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
Failed reading http://ignum.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz: "execution expired"
http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
Failed reading http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz: "getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net:80)"
http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://fco.it.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz exists
http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz ==>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This actually makes sense, the office Internet here can be quite hit or miss. I'll give srt32's suggested updates a shot and see where I'm at from there as soon as I get a chance. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

My error log (/.rvm/log) recommended I brew update but I got an error:

```
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

The log also said:

```
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
```

This is the motherload!  If you have issues with updating rvm, it's likely that you will find your answer here.  After I updated rvm I was able to install ruby.